# How to store Colored Text in a Database Field Using Text instead of RTF ?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, colors, rtf

I've a richtextbox control in a Windows forms application, and there's a VarChar field in a database table that is connected to it. I only need to color some of the words in this richtextbox.  When I save the richtextbox control's `Text` property to the database, it saves only the text without colors so I have to save the richtextbox control's `Rtf` property.  Unfortunately this causes a probelm because when I query my table from the SQL Server Management Studio, or any other way, it shows me the RTF special characters, like this example:

`{\rtf1\fbidis\ansi\ansicpg1256\deff0\deflang3073{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset178 Microsoft Sans Serif;}{\f1\fnil\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}}`

Of course, that prevents me from properly searching or sorting the data because of the RTF characters.

Questions :

1- Is it best to save important data in RTF format in database, and if it's safe and reliable, how can I manipulate the Text in the database without importing it into a richtextbox?

2- The only option I need from the RTF is colored text with background color.  I only need to color my text with 4 colors (red, green, yellow and blue) and to make the background color for some text black.  Is there a way to work with the richtextbox control's `Text` property and save the color property with it? For example, writing a color code before every word that needs to be colored, like  "/R/ for red text /R/" and "/G/ for green text /G/"?

Am I thinking about this right or am I stuck with the RTF?

Answer (score 4):

Things like color is a presentation role, so it shouldn't be in ddbb for regular text. In this case, it's more like a document with formatting, and RTF seems appropriate.

If you need to make queries over this text, you can store the text in a another column as plain text, without formatting.

Comment: what about the size of the table? I'm talking about a daily number of tables exceeds 100 table with large amount of notes stored in RTF

Comment: Well, if size is a problem and you're using SQL Server 2008 or higher, you can store the text in the database for searching and the documents as a filetable in the filesystem. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929144.aspx

Comment: wouldn't it be better if I use only one field in my table to store only the TEXT. and make my own Markup for only 2 colors ? I only want to know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Depend on your design, Oscar's solution is good, you can keep the original color format and queries the plain text. But it looks like it'll increase the storage size. You need to use two column to store the same data only different in formatting.

And your own solution, put a color code in the text is good, but you'll need to do more processing before display (change from color code format to RTF) and before save (change from RTF to color code format).

You also need to consider what if you need more formatting in future? Example: more color, or even need to store style like bold, italic. If this happen, you do not need to change your code if using Oscar's method, but you'll need to change your code if you use your color code method.

Comment: well, I'm sure I'll not need more formatting in the future, the search process will be pretty hard, because I'll search in the TEXT field and show the result highlighted in the RTF field . so is there a good way to put a color code in the text? cuz I still don't know how to do it

Comment: Cannot see why u said it's hard for the search process. Search in TEXT and show RTF is not a problem. Example: SELECT Id, Rtf FROM yourTable WHERE Text LIKE 'Search Criteria'.

Comment: no, I mean searching for WORDS inside the RTF content